# Postgres: does updating column value to the same value marks page as dirty?

Tags: postgresql

Consider following scenario in PostgreSQL (any version from 10+):

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
    id serial primary key,
    name text not null unique,
    last_seen timestamp
);

INSERT INTO users(name, last_seen)
VALUES ('Alice', '2019-05-01'),
       ('Bob', '2019-04-29'),
       ('Dorian', '2019-05-11');

CREATE TABLE inactive_users(
    user_id int primary key references users(id),
    last_seen timestamp not null);

INSERT INTO inactive_users(user_id, last_seen)
SELECT id as user_id, last_seen FROM users 
WHERE users.last_seen < '2019-05-04' 
ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO UPDATE SET last_seen = excluded.last_seen;
```

Now let's say that I want to insert the same values (execute last statement) multiple times, every now and then. In practice from the database point of view, on conflicting values 90% of the time `last_seen` column will be updated to the same value it already had. The values of the rows stay the same, so there's no reason to do I/O writes, right? But is this really the case, or will postgres perform corresponding updates even though the actual value didn't change?

In my case the destination table has dozens of millions of rows, but only few hundreds/thousands of them will be really changing on each of the insert calls.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-trigger.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any `UPDATE` to a row will actually create a new row (marking the old row deleted/dirty), regardless of the before/after values:

```
[root@497ba0eaf137 /]# psql
psql (12.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create table foo (id int, name text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into foo values (1,'a');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select ctid,* from foo;
 ctid  | id | name 
-------+----+------
 (0,1) |  1 | a
(1 row)

postgres=# update foo set name = 'a' where id = 1;
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select ctid,* from foo;
 ctid  | id | name 
-------+----+------
 (0,2) |  1 | a
(1 row)

postgres=# update foo set id = 1 where id = 1;
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select ctid,* from foo;
 ctid  | id | name 
-------+----+------
 (0,3) |  1 | a
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from pg_stat_user_tables where relname = 'foo';
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+-------
relid               | 16384
schemaname          | public
relname             | foo
seq_scan            | 5
seq_tup_read        | 5
idx_scan            | 
idx_tup_fetch       | 
n_tup_ins           | 1
n_tup_upd           | 2
n_tup_del           | 0
n_tup_hot_upd       | 2
n_live_tup          | 1
n_dead_tup          | 2
<...>
```

And according to your example:

```
postgres=# select ctid,* FROM inactive_users ;
 ctid  | user_id |      last_seen      
-------+---------+---------------------
 (0,1) |       1 | 2019-05-01 00:00:00
 (0,2) |       2 | 2019-04-29 00:00:00
(2 rows)

postgres=# INSERT INTO inactive_users(user_id, last_seen)
postgres-# SELECT id as user_id, last_seen FROM users 
postgres-# WHERE users.last_seen < '2019-05-04' 
postgres-# ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO UPDATE SET last_seen = excluded.last_seen;
INSERT 0 2
postgres=# select ctid,* FROM inactive_users ;
 ctid  | user_id |      last_seen      
-------+---------+---------------------
 (0,3) |       1 | 2019-05-01 00:00:00
 (0,4) |       2 | 2019-04-29 00:00:00
(2 rows)
```

Postgres does not do any data validation against the column values -- if you are looking to prevent unnecessary write activity, you will need to surgically craft your `WHERE` clauses.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: If changing the WHERE clause is not an option, an alternative one could be to use a trigger using the the [pre-defined trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-trigger.html) `suppress_redundant_updates_trigger`